# Something ate the Marigolds seedling overnight

Tags: pest-control, seedlings, bugs, rabbits, squirrel

I have my Marigolds seedling for about 3-4 days and suddenly overnight, most leaves are gone

[image]

[image]

I am in Pacific Northwest and we have a lot of bunnies and squirrels.

Any idea which animal or bug would cause this and how to prevent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The most likely culprit is snails or slugs, which operate after dark, and they do like young leaves. Use slug control treatments to protect them.